# Not able to fetch the dropdown data on selecting angular ui-select

Tags: angularjs, typeahead, ui-select, angular-ui-select

I need to fetch the current users list on selecting the ui-select. So, I have implemented it using the ng-focus and it is working in older version(0.8.3) of ui-select. But with the latest version of ui-select, it is not working. It is always showing the default users list.

```
  <ui-select ng-model="user.selected" theme="bootstrap" ng-disabled="disabled" reset-search-input="true" style="width:300px" required>
    <ui-select-match placeholder="Choose One" style="border-color:#ccc;" ng-focus="getCurrentUsersList(user.selected)">{{$select.selected}}
      <button class="clear" ng-click="$event.stopPropagation();user.selected = undefined">x</button>
    </ui-select-match>
    <ui-select-choices repeat="user in usersList | highlight: $select.search" align="left">
      <div ng-bind-html="user | highlight: $select.search"></div>
    </ui-select-choices>
  </ui-select>
```

Here is the plucker link:
http://plnkr.co/edit/VDZ41AIcd5cYwdA9fFPu?p=preview

Comment: You could just do <ui-select ng-init="getCurrentUsersList(user.selected)"

Comment: Then, only for the first time, when ui-select box is being rendered, it fetches the users list. But later again, when we try to change the selected user in it, it will not fetch the users list. I want it to be called everytime whenever we try to select something in the ui-select

Answer (score 0):

Solved this using ng-click

```
  <ui-select ng-model="user.selected" theme="bootstrap" ng-disabled="disabled" reset-search-input="true" style="width:300px" required>
    <ui-select-match placeholder="Choose One" style="border-color:#ccc;" ng-click="getCurrentUsersList(user.selected)">{{$select.selected}}
      <button class="clear" ng-click="$event.stopPropagation();user.selected = undefined">x</button>
    </ui-select-match>
    <ui-select-choices repeat="user in usersList | highlight: $select.search" align="left">
      <div ng-bind-html="user | highlight: $select.search"></div>
    </ui-select-choices>
  </ui-select>
```

Here is the plunker link
http://plnkr.co/edit/VDZ41AIcd5cYwdA9fFPu?p=preview